# insert into table A from table B, if Table B cols count equal to tabl A?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have Table A with 10 columns and Table B has 3 columns only.I want insert Table B data into Table A with and  remaining 7 fields with empty.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

If your table columns has default values then you have to use:-

```
insert into tableA select col1,col2,col3,'','','','','','','' from tableB;
```

for inserting empty values in remaining 7 columns.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
insert into table A(coulmn1,column2,coulmn3)  select * from B;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Insert into tableA(col1, col2, col3) select col1, col2, col3 from tableB 
where col1=condition;
```

Tested in oracle